# Pandas, .agg('sum') vs .sum()

Tags: python, pandas

At the end of my code I sum by dataframe below, then export to csv:

`sumbyname = d5.groupby(['Name'])['Value'].agg('sum')`

I sum the value of each person by name, Now if I sum this column in excel using `SUM` then I get `+12`

Now if i do `d5['Value'].sum())` in my code to find the total sum, I get `-11.`

Is there a difference in the way i'm summing these 2 values? I thought they should be the same.

Comment: Does d5.groupby(['Name'])['Value'].agg('sum').sum() give a different answer than Excel? I suspect Excel is not performing the sum correctly.

Comment: Can you provided the content of `d5`? `d5.to_clipboard(False)` will copy its content to the clipboard so you can paste it into your question

Comment: so if I do `sum(sumbyname)` I get `12`.   but `d5['Value'].sum()` gives `-11` .  `d5.groupby(['Name'])['Value'].agg('sum').sum() ` gives `12` aka same as excel.

Answer (score 1):

The value in column d5['Name'] might contains null values.

Groupby will ignore those rows with None in d5['Name'].